# Persian words in the database and it is issue?

Tags: php, codeigniter, character-encoding

Why insert in database value date as: `&#1588;&#1607;&#1585;&#1610;&#1608;&#1585;` ?

How can search this word in database(شهريور)?

```
 In database: structure => date => varchar(255) => utf8_general_ci = "&#1588;&#1607;&#1585;&#1610;&#1608;&#1585;".
```

Comment: Why are you HTML escaping the string?

Comment: I think the [browser is doing this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231230/persian-words-in-the-database-and-it-is-issue/7231511#7231511)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to html escape those characters as long as you have a UTF* table, and you do.

Simply make sure that the table is UTF8, that the connection is utf8, and the browser reads the texts as utf8.

- for mysql see `SET CHARACTER SET`, `SET NAMES`, `SET COLLATION_CONNECTION`
- for html use `<meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />` and the according http headers, if needed

Answer (score 2):

You website uses an encoding in which these characters do not exists, so the browser sends HTML entities instead.

(Try this here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/dfFMvW ; This page is in ISO-8859-1, if you send non-ISO-8859-1 characters in the input, they are sent as HTML entities.)

---

To avoid this you have to use a different encoding, like UTF-8.

Add this header in your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

Or do this in your PHP before printing anything:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

And make sure your database uses UTF-8 too.

---

You can convert your database to UTF-8 by doing this:

```
ALTER DATABASE your_database CHARACTER SET utf8;
-- for each table:
ALTER TABLE some_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

And after you connect to the database, send this query:

```
SET NAMES UTF8;
```

Comment: A browser sends HTML-entities? Never heard of that…