# Error when insert persian values to my table that have persian name

Tags: php, mysql, database, character-encoding

I have a simple class that should insert my values to my ***`mysql`*** table.

***`The Tables will make by administrator and table names would be in`***  `Persian` , for **example :**

```
DBNAME===>aalborz
TableName==>سارا
```

[image]

### This is my CLASS:

```
<?php
class insertMachine {

    private $_username;
    private $_password;
    private $_dbName;
    private $_tableName;
    private $_host;

    protected $_connection;
    protected $_fields = array();
    protected $_colNames = array();
    protected $_colValues = array();

    public    $_report;


    public function __construct($dbName = 'aalborz', $tableName, $inputValues ) {

        if ( !is_array($inputValues) ) {
            echo 'The Last argument have to be an ARRAY...!!!';
            exit();
        }//if
        else {
            foreach ( $inputValues as $key=>$val ) {

                $this->_colNames[] = $key;
                $this->_colValues[] = $val;



            //  var_dump($this->_colNames);

            }//foreach 

            /*var_dump($this->_colNames, $this->_colValues);*/
        }//else

        $this->_host = 'localhost';
        $this->_dbName =  $dbName;
        $this->_tableName = $tableName;
        $this->_username = 'aalborz';
        $this->_password = 'password';
        $this->_fields = $inputValues;

        try {
            $this->_connection = new PDO('mysql:host = ' . $this->_host . '; dbname = ' . $this->_dbName, $this->_username, $this->_password);
            $this->_connection->exec("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci';");
            $this->_connection->exec("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';");
            $this->_connection->exec("SET character_set_server=utf8");
            $this->_connection->exec("set names utf8 COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");

            /*echo 'Connect shodi';*/
        }//try
        catch( Exception $e ) {
            echo '<pre dir="ltr">';
            die($e);
            echo '</pre>';
        }//catch


    }//__construct

   public function makeQuery() {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . $this->_dbName . "`.`" . $this->_tableName . "` (";

        $numberOfCols = count($this->_colNames);
        $numberOfVals = count($this->_colValues);

        for($i = 0; $i <= $numberOfCols - 1; $i++) {

            if ( $i != $numberOfCols -1 ) {

                $sql .=  "'" . $this->_colNames[$i] . "', ";

            }//if

            else {

                $sql .= "'" .  $this->_colNames[$i] . "') ";

            }//else

        }//for Loop for making first part of Query

        $sql .= " VALUES(";

        for ( $j = 0; $j <= $numberOfVals - 1; $j++) {

            if ( $j != $numberOfVals -1 ) {

                $sql .=  ":" . $this->_colNames[$j] . ", ";
                //$sql .= '? ,';
            }//if
            else {

                $sql .=  ":" . $this->_colNames[$j] . ") ";             
                //$sql .= '? )';

            }//else

        }//for Loop for making Second  part of Query


        //prepare query for insert values
        $prepare = $this->_connection->prepare($sql);

        //execute method for PDO object
        $exe = $prepare->execute( $this->_fields );


        if ( $exe ) {
            $this->_report = '<span style="color:green;">Success...</span>';
        }//if $exe
        else {
            $this->_report = '<span style="color:red;">Fail, Try Again...!!!</span>';
        }//else
        /*echo '<hr />';*/
        echo '<pre dir="ltr">';
        var_dump($sql, $prepare, $exe);
        echo '</pre>';
    }//makeQuery function 


}//CLASS
?>
```

> ***`When I use a table with ENGLISH name, everything is fine, BUT when I test it with persian table, the insert will fail...`***
>   ***`Would you tell me how should I fix this...???`***

I checked this links and questions for my answer but they are not my answer:
[Insert a persian text in mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642755/insert-a-persian-text-in-mysql-table)
[Persian character's issue in mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519496/persian-characters-issue-in-mysql-database)
[Persian words in the database and it is issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231230/persian-words-in-the-database-and-it-is-issue)
[Searching Persian characters and words in SQL server with different encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957438/searching-persian-characters-and-words-in-sql-server-with-different-encoding)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_connection
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I'm checking, thanks for warning, I will delete my post if that was my problem...

Comment: I'm not completely sure as I have never used utf8 characters in table- or column names, but it is a pretty complete guide / checklist.

Comment: I'm trying since 10 hours ago and I have test so many different ways, I'm confused... That question didn't help either, but thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You should set UTF-8 character set for your tables.

```
Database Chartset = utf8 & Database Collation = utf8_general_ci .
```

And you should permanently do it for your tables

That should work! Check below link if it helps as well:

[Insert a persian text in mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642755/insert-a-persian-text-in-mysql-table)

Comment: I updated my answer, as you see in picture, the tables charset are `utf8_general_ci`